# Can I use my PC to make calls from my 640 XL?

Tags: lumia, calls, sound, pc

I have a Lumia 640 XL, and I need to know if there is any method to call someone (using my number phone and the call app), but using my PC as an intermediary.

I have a voice modulator, I want to make some pranks to some friends.

I tried to use a speaker, without luck, because voices are unintelligible.

I'm looking if there is any method to transfer sound using Bluetooth, or connecting an external microphone from a "physical" audio output.